# Можно ли внутри веб страницы открыть вторую веб страницу?

Tags: html, php, javascript

Вопрос довольно таки странный, понимаю. Но есть идея при запуске самого сайта внутри сайта загрузить в отдельном блоке второй сайт, как браузер открывать, но внутри другой страницы. Но чтобы все было полноценно. Чтобы можно было например комментнуть, войти в том псевдо-сайте.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 6):

[iframe](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe)?

> Тег создает плавающий фрейм, который находится внутри обычного документа, он позволяет загружать в область заданных размеров любые другие независимые документы.

Comment: Именно! Как же я мог забыть про него?! Спасибо!

Comment: а почему он не работает??? 

     <iframe src="https://www.google.ru" width="1200" height="700"></iframe>

Comment: Это другой вопрос. Просто потому что это запрещено, многие крупные сайты запрещают это делать.  
Причина проста: любой сайт,который открывает сторонний сайт в iframe может с помощmю яваскрипта получить доступ к различным элементам открытой в iframe страницы...

Comment: Значит этого никак не добиться? Нет обходного пути?

Comment: как мне видится -- нет, но может ктото имеет другую инфу :)

Comment: Браузеры ввели способы запрета отображения сайтов в iframe. [X-Frame-Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx). Если только попробовать вариант через AJAX + CUrl, парсить скрипты и CSS из head и подключать + делать выборку из body. Но не знаю, будет ли работать.

Comment: с ужасом представляю это в применении к мордокниге или гугле :))))

Comment: Насколько помню, протоколы открытой страницы и айфрейма должны совпадать. Во всяком случае в https http открываться не должен, будет ли работать наоборот - не знаю.

Comment: @thunder отсюда поподробнее...

> любой сайт,который открывает сторонний сайт в iframe может с помощmю яваскрипта получить доступ к различным элементам открытой в iframe страницы

Comment: @eicto что именно? это ж везде написано.  

    <form name="formname" .... id="form-first">
        <iframe id="one" src="iframe2.html">
        </iframe>
    </form>
    function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
        return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
    }
    var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementById('one') )

`inside` теперь содержит разметку страницы, загруженной в iframe

    var inside = $('#one').contents();

ну или так

Comment: @thunder, если загружаемое в iframe содержимое находится не в одном домене с основной страницей, то Вы получите ошибку доступа к данным при попытке обратиться к ним.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно

> 1.10.7. Тег `<iframe>`.
> Добавление фрейма в обычный документ
> С помощью парного тега `<iframe>` можно вставлять фреймы в обычный
> HTML-документ. Если тег `<iframe>` не поддерживается, то будет выведен
> текст между тегами `<iframe>` и `</iframe>`. Иногда такие фреймы называют
> "плавающими". Тег `<iframe>` имеет следующие параметры:
>
> - `src` определяет URL-адрес документа, который должен быть загружен во
>   фрейм. Может быть указан абсолютный или относительный URL-адрес:
>
>   ```
>   <iframe src="http://www.mysite.ru/doc2.html">
>   <iframe src="doc2.html">
>   ```
> - `name` задает уникальное имя фрейма:
>
>   ```
>   <iframe src="chapter1.html" name="chapter">
>   ```
> - `scrolling` запрещает или разрешает отображение полос прокрутки во
>   фрейме. Может принимать следующие значения:
>
>   - `auto` — полосы отображаются, только если содержимое не помещает-
>     ся во фрейме (значение по умолчанию):
>
>     ```
>     <iframe src="chapter1.html" name="chapter" scrolling="auto">
>     ```

Это отрывок из книги Прохоренок Н.А. - HTML, JavaScript, PHP и MySQL.  Джентльменский набор Web-мастера (Профессиональное программирование) - 2010.pdf страница 48.